# Trace of continuous function is restriction on boundary.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, trace-map

I was reading a theorem about the trace of a function (taken from Evans' book on PDEs). In the proof, I don't understand the last paragraph. Why the uniform convergence of $u_m$ to $u$ implies $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$ for a function in $W^{1,p}\cap C(\overline{U})$?

> **THEOREM 1** (Trace Theorem)**.** Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $$T : W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$$ such that
>
> $\quad$(i) $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$ if $u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$
>
> and
>
> $\quad$(ii) $$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \le C \| U \|_{W^{1,p} (U)},$$ for each $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, with the constant $C$ depending only on $p$ and $U$.
>
> **DEFINITION.** We call $Tu$ the trace of $u$ on $\partial U$.
>
> **Proof.** 1. Assume first $u \in C^1(\bar{U})$. As in the first part of the proof of Theorem 1 in §5.4 let us also intially suppose $x^0 \in \partial U$ and $\partial U$ is flat near $x^0$, lying in the plane $\{x_n=0\}$. Choose an open ball $B$ as in the previous proof and let $\hat{B}$ denote the concentric ball with radius $r/2$.
>
> $\quad$Select $\zeta \in C_c^\infty(B)$, with $\zeta \ge 0$ in $B$, $\zeta \equiv 1$ on $\hat{B}$. Denote by $\Gamma$ that portion of $\partial U$ within $\hat{B}$. Set $x'=(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} = \{x_n=0\}$. Then
> \begin{align}
> \int_\Gamma |u|^p \, dx' &\le \int_{\{x_n=0\}} \zeta |u|^p \, dx' \\
> &= -\int_{B^+} (\zeta |u|^p)_{x_n} \, dx \\
> &= -\int_B^+ |u|^p \zeta_{x_n} + p|u|^{p-1} (\text{sgn} u)u_{x_n} \zeta \, dx \\
> &\le C \int_{B^+} |u|^p + |Du|^p \, dx,
> \end{align}
>
> 2. If $x^0\in\partial U$, but $\partial U$ is not flat near $x^0$, we as usual straighten out the boundary near $x^0$ to obtrain the setting above. Applying estimate (1) and changing variables, we obtain the bound $$\int_{\Gamma}|u|^pdS\le C\int_U|u|^p+ |Du|^pdx,$$ where $\Gamma$ is some open subset of $\partial U$ containing $x^0$.
> 3. Since $\partial U$ is compact, there exists finitely many points $x_i^0\in\partial U$ and open subsets $\Gamma_i\subset \partial U (i=1,...,N)$ such that $\partial U =\bigcup_{i=1}^N \Gamma_i$ and $$\|u\|_{L^p(\Gamma_i)}\le\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}\quad(i=1,\ldots,N).$$
>
> Consequently, if we write $$Tu:=u|_{\partial U},$$ then $$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)}\le C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$$ for some appropriate constant $C$, which does not depend on $u$.
>
> 4. Inequality (2) holds for $u\in C^1(\overline{U})$. Assume now $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$. Then there exists functions $u_m\in C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ converging to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$. According to (2) we have $$\|Tu_m-Tu_l\|_{L^p(\partial U)}\le C\|u_m-u_l\|_{W^{1,p}(U)};$$ so that $\{Tu_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(\partial U)$. We define $$Tu:=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}Tu_m,$$ the limit taken in $L^p(\partial U)$. According to (3) this definition does not depend on the particular choice of smooth functions approximating $u$.
>
> Finally if $u\in W^{1,p}\cap C(\overline{U})$, we note that the function $u_m\in C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ constructed in the proof of Theorem 3 in paragraph 5.3.3 converges uniformly to $u$ on $\overline{U}$. Hence $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, the trace $Tu$ is defined as the limit in $L^p(\partial U)$ of the functions $Tu_m:=u_m|_{\partial U}$ where $u_m\in C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ converge to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$ (and the limit is shown to be independent of the choice of the approximating sequence $\{u_m\}$.). Now if $u_m$ converge uniformly to $u$ in $\bar{U}$ (which is the case for $u\in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$), then the uniform convergence also holds on $\partial U$, so (since the measure used on   $ \partial U$ is finite) $u_m|_{\partial U}\to u|_{\partial U}$ in $L^p(\partial U)$  as well. Uniqueness of limits in $L^p(\partial U)$ then guarantees that $u|_{\partial U}=Tu$ as members of $L^p(\partial U)$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. When you say $u_m|_{\partial U}\to u|_{\partial U}$ I am not sure what $u|_{\partial U}$ means. Isn't the map $u$ defined up to zero measure and couldn't its restriction on the boundary take any values? Are you maybe defining $u|_{\partial U}:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_m|_{\partial U}$?

Comment: @edamondo Since $u$ is assumed to be continuous in the closure $\bar{U}$, its values are determined at every point of $\bar{U}$.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. This clarifies the doubt I had. One last point that is not 100% clear to me is the implication "the measure used on $ \partial U$ is finite"  $\implies u_m|_{\partial U}\to u|_{\partial U}$

Comment: On a finite measure space, uniform convergence implies $L^p$ convergence.

Comment: Thanks so much. And juste to be sure :  when we say the measure of $\partial U$ is finite, it is even zero right?

Comment: @edamondo When  Evans writes $$T : W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$$ the measure on $\partial U$ is the surface measure obtained locally from projection to the tangent plane. You can see this in the proof, which starts with the flat case, where the measure is just $n-1$ dimensional Lebesgue measure. So the surface measure of $\partial U $ is finite because $U$ is bounded and  $\partial U $ is $C^1$. But this measure is certainly not zero.